# Python @propertie attribute does not appear on the object's dictionar

Tags: python, properties

Why when I'd call a.__dict__ the output isn't {name:'rafael',age:28}?

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.name = 'Rafael'

    @property
    def age(self):
        return 28

a = Person()
print a.__dict__
```

Answer (score 2):

The property object itself is in `Person.__dict__`:

```
In [16]: Person.__dict__
Out[16]: dict_proxy({'__module__': '__main__', 'age': <property object at 0xa387c0c>, '__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'Person' objects>, '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Person' objects>, '__doc__': None, '__init__': <function __init__ at 0xa4d66f4>})
```

`a.age` is the return value of a function call. It uses the [descriptor lookup mechanism](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/) to call `Person.__dict__['age'].__get__(a,Person)`.

Python does not store `{'age':28}` in any `__dict__` since the 28 is not necessarily a fixed value. That function called could conceivably return a different value with every call. So it would be meaningless to associate `'age'` with just one return value.

Consider, for example,

```
class Person(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.count = 0
    @property
    def age(self):
        self.count += 1
        return self.count    

a = Person()
print(a.age)
# 1
print(a.age)
# 2
```